# slam problem with information about depth and position

Tags: slam

I am trying to solve a slam problem for a unicycle moving on a plane. The sensor is a camera (eyes3d) that can provide the distance of the camera from a certain landmark and the position of the landmark on the image plane. For the estimation I want to use ekf. How can I parameterize the landmark state? I have read something about inverse distance: the landmark is parameterized with 2 angles, the position xi and yi and the inverse distance. In my case the distance is a measurement. Do I have to insert it in the state that describes the landmark positioning? thanks

Comment: It is not clear what information is available to you, or exactly what it is you are trying to calculate. Are you asking how to localize the unicycle within a coordinate system? How would you solve this using simple geometry? Please edit your post to add this information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.